# How to fetch unsaved data from CoreData from background thread in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I created a NSManagedObjectContext using:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

Then I make an API call with AlamoFire and in the callback I try to save the parent:

```
let objectDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Parent", in: managedObjectContext)
var managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: objectDescription!, insertInto: managedObjectContext) as? Parent
```

Which completes successfully (yay!)

Then I make an API call to get their children and in the callback I try to fetch the parents in order to link them:

```
let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Parent> = NSFetchRequest<Parent>(entityName: "Parent")
fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = true
let result = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

Now I'm getting `result.count = 0`

Those two CoreData operations are occurring in different threads, and I feel this is the problem... Is it really? How do I solve this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The managed object context is often referred to as a "scratch pad". Any changes you make to it are only in memory, until you save() them. Even after a save, if your context has a parent context, those changes still may not hit the actual DB, until *that* parent context saves, etc.

So yes, manipulating Core Data on multiple threads is what is causing your issue. The usual solution is to use a single background context to persist changes you get back from a server, so that those changes are serialized against one another.